# Showing uniqueness of solution of nonhomogeneous heat equation PDEs of this form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Given the following inhomogeneous heat equation, how to show that the solution is unique?:

$\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t}- K\frac{\partial^2 v(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=-c{v(x,t)}+y(x)$

$  x\in[0,L]$

IC: $ v(0,0) = v(L,0) = 0 $ and is twice cont. diff.

BC: $ v(0,t) = v(L,t) = 0 $

The constants c, K and L are all $> 0$

$y$ is cont. on $[0,L]$

I'm wondering if these kind of PDE's can rewritten as:

$ 
\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t}- K\frac{\partial^2 v(x,t)}{\partial x^2}= k$

The last is one of which i guess can be solved by showing that only 1 unique solution exists by introducing a new function $w$ which is equal to the difference of 2 solutions $w_1 - w_2$. Since these are equal the k cancels out. Writing it down:

$ 
\frac{\partial w_1(x,t)}{\partial t}- K\frac{\partial^2 w_1(x,t)}{\partial x^2}= k$

$ 
\frac{\partial w_2(x,t)}{\partial t}- K\frac{\partial^2 w_2(x,t)}{\partial x^2}= k$

So $w = w_1 - w_2$ which yields the homogeneous equation 
$\frac{\partial w(x,t)}{\partial t}- K\frac{\partial^2 w(x,t)}{\partial x^2}= 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation can be rewritten using the transformation $\tilde{v}(x,t)={\rm e}^{ct}v(x,t)$.  Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tilde{v}(x,t)=&{\rm e}^{ct}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(x,t)+c{\rm e}^{ct}v(x,t)\\
=&K\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\tilde{v}(x,t)+{\rm e}^{ct}y(x)
\end{align}
Without this transformation if you had two solutions you can take the difference $w=v_1-v_2$ and $w$ would solve homogeneous equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} w(x,t)=K\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}w(x,t)-cw(x,t)
\end{align}
A good method to prove uniqueness is the energy method where you consider
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^L\frac{1}{2}w(x,t)^2dx=&\int_0^L w(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}w(x,t)dx\\
=&\int_0^L w(x,t)\left(K\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}w(x,t)-cw(x,t)\right)dx\\
=&-\int_0^L\left( K\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}w(x,t)\right]^2+cw(x,t)^2\right)dx\leq 0
\end{align}
Thus the $L^2$ norm of $w$ is not increasing so if it begins as zero it will remain zero, which implies that $w(x,t)=0$.  Importantly, you need the correct initial conditions $w(x,0)=0$ for $x\in [0,L]$.

Comment: Does that transformation/method have a name? I'm wondering why/how that transformation applies. So that transformation is an alternative to the dfference $w$?

Comment: I would refer to it at discounting.  If $\tilde{v}$ is a cost, then $v$ is a discounted cost with a discounting factor of $c$.  This is coming from a perspective of optimal control type problems.  I would not see it as an alternative to the difference based methods as the transformation by itself does not prove uniqueness.  It may make it easier to make use of other techniques.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering how the K dissapears or has it been forgotten?
How do you get the first term of the last integral to be negative?

Comment: Sorry, the K should appear in the last line; I will edit it in.  This term (with quadratic derivatives) shows up from integration by parts with respect to the $x$ variable.  The boundary terms are zero due to the boundary conditions and the sign change is from the integration by parts formula.  Then the integral is non-positive because everything appears squared and $K>0$ and $c>0$.